# $a^{\phi(n)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ need not imply that $a$ is a quadratic residue, why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a^{\phi(n)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ need not imply that $a$ is a quadratic residue, why ?

---

My question comes from Euler's criterion which says that $$a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p} \implies \text{ a is a quadratic residue}$$

Why the Euler's criterion works only for odd prime moduli ?
What exactly breaks down when the modulus is composite ?
Any help ?

Comment: If you examine a proof of Euler's criterion, it will be clear where it breaks down for composite moduli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $G=\mathbb{Z}/(m\mathbb{Z})^*$ is not always a cyclic group for composite $m$, hence $a^{|G|/2}$ does not give the Legendre symbol. For istance, if $m=15=3\cdot 5$, we have that $2$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{3}$ neither $\pmod{5}$, so it is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{15}$, but:

$$ 2^{\varphi(15)/2}= 2^4\equiv 1\pmod{3}, \qquad 2^{4}\equiv 1\pmod{15},$$
hence $2^{4}\equiv 1\pmod{15}$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Ahh nothing better than a counter example xD makes sense thanks a lot ! :)